# React and Restful web service api communication

Tags: web-services, rest, api, reactjs, restful-architecture

I have a trouble about reactjs and restful web service api architecture. In the common case this would not be a problem but if i have situation like this.
I have React web consumes api data from many database table (these tables are related) on server in one page (in react it would be split into multiple components)

But i learnt that in term of restful web service we should have 1 url for 1 resource which is a database table. if we need related resource we could use nested url. let me give an example. I have 4 database tables which is Bill, Work Order, Sale Job and Product. with these relationships. Bill has one Work Order, Work Order has many Sale Jobs and Sale Job has one Product.
if i need all data for this react page i need at least 4 http requests. with url nested approach, like below.

```
1. /api/bills/1
2. /api/bills/1/workOrder
3. /api/bills/1/workOrder/saleTxns
4. /api/bills/1/workOrder/saleTxns/product
```

or another way is to just let bill url have all nested data i need for this react page (which is gigantic) so i can just have 1 http request and pass all data into each component.

So my question is which approach is better.

1. split into multiple chunk of data.

   - so then. Will it be root component job to 
     fetch data and pass into child component. or each component fetch its own 
     data.
2. just load 1 gigantic request.

   - is this will be bad practice for restful web 
     service? cause it looks like i design url /api/bills/1 for just this react 
     web page. so if i have more platform like ios, android then i need to have 
     more url for it? 
     maybe like.

     - /web/api/bills/1?reactView1=true,
     - /web/api/bills/1?reactView2=true,
     - /ios/api/bills/1
     - /android/api/bills/1

Comment: "in term of restful web service we should have 1 url for 1 resource which is a database table". No, that's flatly Wrong, in the same way that having one screen per database table is Wrong. The database should store data in the most convenient way. The API should provide data in a shape that the client needs, not in a shape that's convenient for database storage. REST deals only with the shape of the API. It says nothing about any other layers.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say which approach is better based on your information. What I *can* say, however, is this:

- As Eric Stein says, there is no requirement to allow only one url to correspond with one database table.
- If this is a common operation in your front end, it makes sense to develop an API endpoint such, that it responds with all the information nested below the specified `bill`. It saves you some front end code / nasty callback logic.
- That being said, doing 4 requests should not be the end of the world either. If this fits the rest of your application better, and you developed the logic in a decent way, this shouldn't be too much of a problem.
- Which component should handle which action is again really up to how your application is designed and how you want to continue to build it out. Don't be too afraid to just start with one approach, maybe you should change it later. It's code after all, not concrete.